# After resize in partitions, OS X won’t boot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition

I apologise if I’m not providing enough information, as this is the first time I’m asking for help this way, please bear with me. :)

I resized partitions last night; windows kept complain about not having enough space, so I followed these instructions: https://youtu.be/-WRkeL1Lnq8

Now, when I want to reboot, only windows shows up. Please help?

Comment: press and hold "option" key  while restarting, do u  see any  partitions  there ??

Comment: Just windows. :( when I load up my disk partition software it suddenly says “438GB unallocated”. Probably means OS is gone, right?

Comment: You can start by providing some information about your Mac. Do you know the model/year? If you can boot to internet recovery and post the output from the commands `diskutil list`, `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `fdisk /dev/disk0`, then I would have more information.